# Cálculo financeiro com números decimais grandes

Tags: java

Eu havia criado o código abaixo para cálculo de financiamento. Converti a matemática para o código Java, utilizei variáveis do tipo `double`.

Mas o resultado deu *infinity*, estou tentando usar o `BigDecimal`, estou perdido, as linhas que apresentam estar com erro tem os comentários indicando isso.

```
BigDecimal pv = new BigDecimal(txtValor.getText());
BigDecimal taxa = new BigDecimal(txtTaxa.getText());
int prazo = Integer.parseInt(txtPrazo.getText());


double porcento = taxa / 100; // Erro aqui

for(int parcela=1; parcela <= pv; parcela++){ // Erro aqui

    double j1 = 1+porcento;
    double j2;
    j2 = Math.pow(j1, prazo);
    double j3 = 1-j2;
    double j4 = taxa / j3; // Erro aqui
    double j5 = pv * j4; // Erro aqui

    lP1.setText(Double.toString(parcela));
    lV1.setText(Double.toString(j5));
```

Comment: `pv` significa *valor presente* e não número de parcelas. Dentro do cálculo, você tem que usar a exponenciação com o número da parcela, ou então todas as parcelas seriam iguais e não é esse o propósito. Veja mais na minha resposta lá em baixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, questiono se o cálculo está correto, afinal de contas, você não está usando a variável `parcela` nele. Além disso `pv` significa *valor presente*, e não número de parcelas, logo não faz sentido iterar-se o número de parcelas até o `pv`. Faz sentido iterar-se até o `prazo` se este corresponder ao número de parcelas. Dentro do cálculo de cada parcela, elevar uma variável ao expoente dado pelo valor presente também não faz sentido, mas ao número da parcela sim. **É por isso que o seu cálculo não funciona e resulta em *infinity*.**

Depois, você usa os métodos de `BigDecimal` para fazer as contas. Em especial, os métodos a usar são o [`add(BigDecimal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add-java.math.BigDecimal-), o [`subtract(BigDecimal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#multiply-java.math.BigDecimal-), o [`multiply(BigDecimal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#multiply-java.math.BigDecimal-), o [`divide(BigDecimal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-) e o [`pow(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#pow-int-).

Você também pode usar o [construtor que recebe um `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-int-) para converter um `int` em um `BigDecimal`. Quando o valor a ser convertido for 0, 1 ou 10, você pode usar os campos estáticos [`BigDecimal.ZERO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ZERO), [`BigDecimal.ONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ONE) e [`BigDecimal.TEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#TEN).

Eis como fica o código:

```
private static final BigDecimal CEM = new BigDecimal(100);

// ...

BigDecimal bigPv = new BigDecimal(txtValor.getText());
BigDecimal taxa = new BigDecimal(txtTaxa.getText());
int prazo = Integer.parseInt(txtPrazo.getText());

BigDecimal porcento = taxa.divide(CEM);
BigDecimal j1 = porcento.add(BigDecimal.ONE);

for (int parcela = 1; parcela <= prazo; parcela++) {
    BigDecimal j2 = j1.pow(parcela);
    BigDecimal j3 = BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(j2);
    BigDecimal j4 = taxa.divide(j3);
    BigDecimal j5 = j4.multiply(pv);

    lP1.setText(String.valueOf(parcela));
    lV1.setText(j5.toPlainString());
```

No final, você não precisa converter o `BigDecimal` para `Double` para então colocar no `lV1`, basta usar o método [`toPlainString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString--). É importante não confundir ele com o [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString--) e o [`toEngineeringString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toEngineeringString--) que têm um funcionamento um pouco diferente.

Observe que eu mantive a criação do `CEM` e o `j1` fora do `for` por uma questão de desempenho, para que não seja necessário ficar sempre se recriando os mesmos `BigDecimal`s. O `j1` não depende do valor da `parcela`, apenas do da `taxa`, logo pode ficar fora do `for`. No caso do `CEM`, como ela é uma constante, coloquei como estático.

Também noto que o `lP1.setText` e o `lV1.setText` dentro do `for` não deve ser o que você quer, pois apenas o último valor computado vai permanecer.

Um outro porém é que você decidiu usar `BigDecimal` porque estava obtendo *infinity* como resultado. Ocorre que o problema real é que a sua forma de cálculo estava errada (tal como expliquei no primeiro parágrafo). Usar `BigDecimal` não resolveria o problema de usar a fórmula errada. Assim sendo, você poderia voltar a usar `double`, embora eu não recomende, pois `BigDecimal` é o recomendável para cálculos financeiros.

Por fim, recomendo você revisar o cálculo acima, pois embora eu tenha percebido um erro na sua forma de realizar o cálculo, isso não significa que não existam outros erros.

Answer (score 2):

Pra trabalhar com `BigDecimal`, bem, você precisa usar `BigDecimal`.

As operações com `BigDecimal` são usando os métodos que a própria classe possui

- `add()` para somar
- `substract()` para subtratir
- `divide()` para dividir
- `multiply()` para multiplicar

E você necessariamente precisa passar um BigDecimal como valor

```
BigDecimal pv = new BigDecimal("200.0");
BigDecimal taxa = new BigDecimal("10");
int prazo = 10;


BigDecimal porcento = taxa.divide(new BigDecimal("100"));

for(int parcela=1; parcela <= pv.intValue(); parcela++){

    BigDecimal j1 = porcento.add(new BigDecimal("1"));
    BigDecimal j2 = j1.pow(prazo);
    BigDecimal j3 = new BigDecimal("1").subtract(j2);
    BigDecimal j4 = taxa.divide(j3);
    BigDecimal j5 = pv.multiply(j4);

    lP1.setText(Double.toString(parcela));
    lV1.setText(Double.toString(j5.doubleValue()));
}
```

E claro, você consegue extrair valores `inteiros` e `doubles` de um `BigDecimal` usando os métodos

- `intValue()` para extrair o valor `inteiro`
- `doubleValue()` para extrair o valor `double` // no caso, esse é o que foi utilizado no código que passei pra poder setar em `lV1`

Comment: Use `BigDecimal.ONE`, `BigDecimal.TEN`, `new BigDecimal(100)` e `new BigDecimal(200)`.

Comment: No `j3` você inverteu a ordem dos números na subtração.

Comment: Por que você declara a veriável `decimal` com o 200? Você não a usa para nada e ela também não estava no código original.

Comment: o `new BigDecimal(200)` foi sem querer, já retirei e tentei fazer o mais didático possível.

Comment: Sobe o que o Victor falou ao usar `BigDecimal.ONE`: se essas contas são coisas frequentes, é melhor você usar uma única variável do que ficar criando mais e mais variáveis com o `new`. Isso vai diminuir o _memory footprint_ da aplicação. Eu inclusive faria `BigDecimal.TEN.movePointRigth(1)` para representar o 100, visando tirar da minha responsabilidade alocar espaço para o 100, permitindo ao Java usar algum _buffer_ ocasional

Comment: Sim, com certeza! Esse código poderia ser melhorado bastante. Mas tentei ser didático no que se refere a usar a classe BigDecimal.

Answer (score -1):

Muito obrigado a todos, como tinha ficado sem net tentei resolver o problema por mim mesmo e consegui de uma forma simples. Corrigi a lógica do meu código.

As respostas de vocês me ensinaram a entender o BigDecimal, obrigado mesmo. Henrique Santiago && Victor Stafusa

Segue o código como ficou caso alguém queira ver

```
double pv = Double.parseDouble(txtValor.getText());
double taxa = Double.parseDouble(txtTaxa.getText());
double prazo = Double.parseDouble(txtPrazo.getText());


double porcento = taxa / 100;

double j1 = 1 + porcento;
double j2 = Math.pow(j1, prazo);
double j3 = 1 / j2;
double j4 = 1 - j3;
double j5 = porcento / j4;
double j6 = pv * j5;
lV1.setText(Double.toString(j6));

double valorTotal = j6 * prazo;
lVt.setText(Double.toString(valorTotal));

double totalJuros = valorTotal - pv;
lVtJ.setText(Double.toString(totalJuros));
```